# Regarding manipulating the dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve the following :

1. I have been given a time series data with 3 columns - "Timestamp,Lag1_Timestamp, MyData", where Lag1_Timestamp is the timestamp lagged by 1.
2. I have to first create another column **time_diff = Timestamp - Lag1_Timestamp**, with the constraint, that whenever I encounter MyData=0, then the time_diff = 0.

   > val df3 = df2.withColumn("time_diff", when(df2("Timestamp") === 0, 0).otherwise(when (df2("MyData") === 0, 0).otherwise((df2("Timestamp")-df2("Lag1_Timestamp")))))
3. Once the **time_diff** is calculated, I need to calculate the cumulative sum as follows :

a. Start the cumulative sum at '0' so for timestamp 0 , the cum_sum = 0

b. Then keep finding the cumulative sum for each record. (Assume the data frames are sorted by timestamp).

c. But whenever you encounter the value of **time_diff=0**, you restart the cumulative sum to 0 and restart the cumulative sum from that point.

```
val list = df3.collect()
val cumSum = Array.ofDim[Double](list.length);
for((cur,i) <- list.view.zipWithIndex){
  if(i!=0){
    var prev = list(i-1);
    if(prev(1)!=0 && cur(1)!=0){
       cumSum(i) = cumSum(i-1) + cur(3).asInstanceOf[Double] + prev(3).asInstanceOf[Double]
    }
  }
}
val summing = sc.parallelize(cumSum).toDF("Uptime")
def addIndex(df: DataFrame) = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  // Add index
  df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map{case (r, i) => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ i)},
  // Create schema
  StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("_index", LongType, false))
)
// Add indices
val aWithIndex = addIndex(inDF)
val bWithIndex = addIndex(summing)

// Join and clean
val ab1 = aWithIndex
  .join(bWithIndex, Seq("_index")).orderBy(asc("Timestamp"))
  .drop("_index")
```

Though the code works, it's very slow. My question is if there is a better way to achieve the same target as mentioned above.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: If you are trying to achieve cumulative sum over all dataset then distributed system for such task is a bad choice. A simple machine with high processing unit would outperform the task than a distributed system. so I would suggest you to group the dataset

Comment: @RameshMaharjan : Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate what you meant by grouping the dataset? Did you mean partitioning the dataset based on a key and then working on the individual sets.